# Multiple insert queries on an Oracle server "SQL command not properly ended"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to execute multiple insert queries in one go, to do this I am building the statements and copying them in all in one go and then executing everything below is an example of this:

```
insert into capd_student (S_ID, S_StudentReference) 
   values ('186000377936135','s0253166')
insert into capd_student (S_ID, S_StudentReference) 
   values ('186000377936136','s0253166')
insert into capd_student (S_ID, S_StudentReference) 
   values ('186000377936137','s0253166')
```

The error I am recieving is "SQL command not properly ended", I have tried to use a semi colon at the end also and this has given me an "invalid character" error.

Comment: Which (client) tool do you use to run those statements?

Comment: I have tried this using Unit-e Query executor, and the query designer in Microsoft report builder both throwing up the same errors.

Comment: Did you try using a "native" Oracle tool like SQL Developer or SQL*Plus?  In general SQL statements need to be terminated with `;`. (I'm not surprised that the Microsoft tool doesn't honor them though)

Answer (score 0):

Well you definitely need semicolons at the end of each statement. In SQL, you split up statements by semicolons, but the last statement doesn't need one. So if you wanted, you could leave off a semicolon at the end.

This leads you to the next error, which is an invalid character. Double check your column names, remembering that SQL names are case-sensitive, and try caps on INSERT, INTO, and VALUES. Also, you could try adding a space after the comma in the value parameters.

EX:

```
INSERT INTO capd_student (S_ID, S_StudentReference) VALUES ('186000377936135', 's0253166');
```

Comment: Millar,Welcome to SO.! In Oracle, SQL names are `case-sensitive`? No, they are not, unless you specify them(just few db objects) between [double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468337/oracle-sql-syntax-quoted-identifier). Still the keywords are *NOT* Case-Sensitive. Space after comma is a good practice, but it is not an issue!

Comment: Aha thanks. Thought I'd give it my best go. Seems like some kinda easy fix, but he might not be using SSMS. Cheers.