# PLS-00201 identifier "rep_table_T" must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to compile this procedure. I whish it gets table row as parameter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MY_HELPER (rep_table_row IN OUT rep_table_T%ROWTYPE)  IS
...
END MY_HELPER ;
```

The table is defined as

```
create or replace TYPE         "rep_table_T" AS TABLE OF rep_table_O;
```

The object is defined as:

```
create or replace TYPE         "rep_table_O" AS OBJECT (       
    "day" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
    "TS" DATE
    );
```

However I can't compile it because  I'm getting the error:

```
PLS-00201 identifier "rep_table_T" must be declared.
```

Comment: You should get the error `PLS-00201 identifier 'REP_TABLE_O' must be declared`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=79e4e26a92e425f0f221c583b9dd6ad0)

Comment: Did you read [the reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA)? *A **quoted identifier** begins and ends with double quotation marks ("). If you name a schema object using a quoted identifier, **then you must use the double quotation marks whenever you refer to that object**.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ORA-00904: invalid identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027961/ora-00904-invalid-identifier) [Oracle SQL Syntax: Quoted identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468337/oracle-sql-syntax-quoted-identifier)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the %ROWTYPE.  That only applies to actual sql tables, not pl/sql collections.  From the documentation, "The %ROWTYPE attribute provides a record type that represents a row in a database table. "

Yeah it is very confusing as a new user that oracle calls actual tables and pl/sql tables the same thing.

Comment: Is it then possible to pass rowtype of collection as parameter?

Comment: No.  Why do you need to even do that?

Comment: Because let say I have 
`rep_table rep_table_T;`
`myIdx BINARY_INTEGER;` 
I wish to pass to the procedure `rep_table (myIdx )` instead of  `rep_table`;

Answer (score 1):

Forget about double quotes while in Oracle. If you use them while creating any objects, you have to use them always.

As of your code: removed double quotes, removed `rowtype` in procedure declaration.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rep_table_o AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     day VARCHAR2 (250 BYTE),
  4     ts DATE
  5  );
  6  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rep_table_t AS TABLE OF rep_table_o;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_helper (
  2     rep_table_row  IN OUT rep_table_t)
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     NULL;
  6  END my_helper;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two errors:

1. Do not use quoted identifiers:

   ```sql
   CREATE TYPE rep_table_O AS OBJECT (       
     day VARCHAR2(250 BYTE),
     TS  DATE
   );

   CREATE TYPE rep_table_T AS TABLE OF rep_table_O;
   ```

   (Or, if you really must have lower-case identifiers [why?] then you need to use quoted identifiers, with exactly the same case, **everywhere** that identifier is used.)
2. Do not use `%ROWTYPE`:

   ```sql
   CREATE PROCEDURE MY_HELPER (
     rep_table_row IN OUT rep_table_T
   )
   IS
     ...
   END MY_HELPER;
   ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=07eee6ebfe18c5b62059081810b13c4c)*